# The body in the cellar

Tags: knowledge, visual, board-games

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #7: Board games](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7441/monthly-topic-challenge-7-board-games?cb=1).</sub>

---

On a cold December night in 1992, several guests have arrived at a mansion in Beverly, Massachusetts.
An hour later, the body of the host is found in the cellar.

You have been asked to solve the crime.
All you have is a map of the mansion showing some rooms and halls of white and orange tile.   Unfortunately, it is inaccurate! Exactly 8 white tiles should be orange instead.

Who murdered the host? Where? And with what?

[image: map]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The host was murdered:

> By Reverend Green, in the Kitchen, with the Wrench.

Because:

> This is clearly a Cluedo board, but some of the passageways are a bit wonky, and what's with all the orange?
>  With all the rooms blacked out, it looks more like a crossword grid, but we don't have any clues....

> But maybe we don't need any.
>  A bit of counting (treating the orange squares as black) shows we have roughly the right number of entries/lengths to fill the grid with all the locations, suspects and weapons from the game.
>  And maybe the missing orange squares will help to sort out any mismatch.

> Filling this in was more straightforward than I was expecting.
>  Starting with the long and short entries, the grid can quite easily be completed, giving (Extra orange cells coloured green for clarity):
>  [image]

> And in classic Cluedo style, we have one location, weapon and suspect left over once the grid has been filled:
>  Reverend Green
>  Kitchen
>  Wrench

Comment: As someone who’s never even seen a board from the game in question, much less played the game, I have to say there is no way in hell I would ever have come anywhere near thinking of this. I can only assume that ‘soorry’ here is aimed at people like me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: There are 2 hints. First, it's part of the Board Game challenge, so a Board Game must be involved. Second, the host being murdered by one of the guests is exactly the plot of Cluedo. Doesn't mean I made the link without first reading this answer, but those are good clues...

Comment: The real mystery is why the puzzle is set in Massachusetts, USA, but uses the non-USA version of the red character's name. There was not a second "T" in the name in 1992.

Comment: @EngineerToast Oops! I have edited to fix the grid; somehow I messed that up. The production year/city were indeed intended to point to the exact version in case it helped (and serve as hints based on games produced in that time and city).

Comment: @MatthieuM. I knew the basic premise of the game, but I had no idea what the board looked like (in fact, I didn’t even know this game _had_ a board). My comment was mostly to express that I’m forever impressed with the ingenious leaps, connections and deductions people here are able to make, often in seemingly no time at all.